# How find this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\zeta_{n}(3)}{n}=?$

Tags: summation

**Question:**

> show that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\zeta_{n}(3)}{n}=\dfrac{19\pi^4}{1440}-\dfrac{3}{4}\zeta{(3)}\ln{2}?$$

where $$\zeta_{n}(3)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^3}$$

But I use this computer find this [image]

and my reslut is wrong? Thank you

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to add up a few terms to see which answer must be wrong.

Comment: I input this into mathematica 9.0.1 and it did not give Log[2]Zeta[3] and actually didn't simplify it at all.

Comment: I got a completely closed solution. Ckeck it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\zeta_{n}\pars{3} \over n}
     ={19\pi^{4} \over 1440} - {3 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}\ln\pars{2}:\ {\large ?}.
     \qquad \zeta_{n}\pars{3} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k^{3}}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
> {\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\zeta_{n}\pars{3} \over n}}
> =\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k^{3}}
> =\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{3}}
> \color{#00f}{\sum_{n = k}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\sum_{n = k}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n}}\color{#00f}
=\sum_{n = k}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = k}^{\infty}\pars{-x}^{n - 1}\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{-x}^{k - 1} \over 1 - \pars{-x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{-x}^{k - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
> {\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\zeta_{n}\pars{3} \over n}}
> =\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{3}}
> \int_{0}^{1}{\pars{-x}^{k - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
> =-\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k^{3}}
> \,{1 \over x\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{-x} \over x\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{-1}^{0}{{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{x} \over x\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{-1}^{0}{{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> +\int_{-1}^{0}{{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-{\rm Li}_{4}\pars{-1} + {\rm Li}_{3}\pars{-1}\ln\pars{2}
> +\int_{-1}^{0}\ln\pars{1 - x}{\rm Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-{\rm Li}_{4}\pars{-1} + {\rm Li}_{3}\pars{-1}\ln\pars{2}
> -\int_{-1}^{0}x{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\zeta_{n}\pars{3} \over n}}
&={\large-{\rm Li}_{4}\pars{-1} + {\rm Li}_{3}\pars{-1}\ln\pars{2}
+\half\,{\rm Li}_{2}^{2}\pars{-1}}
\\[3mm]\mbox{and}&\qquad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
{\rm Li}_{4}\pars{-1} & = & -\,{7\pi^{4} \over 720}
\\
{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{-1} & = & -\,{3 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}
\\
{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-1} & = & -\,{\pi^{2} \over 12}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\zeta_{n}\pars{3} \over n}
>      ={19\pi^{4} \over 1440} - {3 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}\ln\pars{2}}
> \approx 0.6604
> $$

Answer (score 6):

Let us recall the integral representation for a more general case that I introduced in a [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/276590#276590)

> $$ A(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H^{(p)}_k}{k^q} = \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^{q}}{\Gamma(q)}\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { \left( \ln\left( u
>  \right)  \right)^{q-1}{Li_{p}(-u)} }{ u\left( 1+
> u \right) }}{du}.$$

where $Li_{p}(-u)$ is the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Your sum can be written (see [generalized harmonic numbers](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber2/02/)) as

> $$ A(3,1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H^{(3)}_k}{k}= -\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { {Li_{3}(-u)} }{ u\left( 1+ u \right) }}{du}$$

$$ = \int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { {Li_{3}(-u)} }{ \left( 1+ u \right) }}{du}-\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { {Li_{3}(-u)} }{ u }}{du} $$

$$ = \left(-\frac{3}{4}\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \zeta  \left( 3 \right) +{\frac {1}{288}}\,{\pi }^{4}\right) - \left(- \frac{7}{720}\pi^4\right)$$

> $$ \implies A(3,1) = \frac{19}{1440}\pi^4-\frac{3}{4}\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \zeta  \left( 3 \right). $$

**Note:** To evaluate the integrals you can use integration by parts with $u={Li_{3}(-u)}$ or use computer algebra systems.